# Combining two iOS Apps

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework

I have two apps (App1 and App2). App2 is built with Ionic framework.

I need to combine them in a way that I can have a button in App1 that after clicked open App2 and I can perform all App2's functionalities.

I can't create a new app recoding both apps, because they are from different developers.

I think that i should convert App2 to a framework and import it into App1, but I don't know how to do that, and all of my attempts failed.

I don't really need to hide the app's code so if there is a simpler solution than framework it can be done.

If somebody can help me with my issue i would really appreciate.

Comment: Can you just drag the app2 project into the app1 project in xcode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow below steps:

1) Create sub-folder in your project and add framework into that folder.

2) Now, open Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries. And click on '+' button.

3) Then click on "Add Other" instead of adding default framework.

Now, you have added framework successfully. That's it.

Comment: ok but I still have to know how to convert my App2 into a framework and the add it to App1 right? Or can I link the App2's project?

Comment: You may check some tutorials how to make framework, here is one example http://www.raywenderlich.com/65964/create-a-framework-for-ios